# PowerBI date button -1 day and +1 day

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table that is filtered to show TOP 1 data ( numbers ). Now I need a back and forward button so it should change -1 or +1 day. Does anyone know a tutorial or a documentation for this? Tried googling it without any helpful results.

Comment: it's not possible to have an advance a day +/- button, even with bookmarks. You will have to use a date slicer, set in slider mode, that will allow you to pick a date

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [bookmarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-bookmarks) and [buttons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-buttons)?

You could create some buttons to manage this scenario.

Comment: My data is filtered by TOP N ( 1 ) this means it always shows the most recent data, now I don't know how to filter it to show 2 days, 3 days etc before so making bookmarks doesn't really help me out here. I need to use DAX or M language or something to get the -1 day or +1 day result.